# Countdown en javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito un timer (coutdown), de espera de 10 segundos para la descarga, JavaScript. Después de los 10 segundos esconder ese texto. Por ejemplo:

Quedan 10 segundos...
Quedan 9 segundos...
Y así sucesivamente y mostrar un botón...

No quiero un texto que diga Espere 10 segundos, quiero que muestre cuantos segundos quedan y esconder ese texto para mostrar el botón de descarga.

Gracias.

Comment: Pon el código que tienes hasta ahora para ver si te podemos ayudar con el problema específico.

Comment: En este sitio se tratan dudas y problemas de programación. ¿Cuál es la tuya?

Comment: Javier, click aquí por favor: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour es muy importante que todo usuario aprenda a realizar preguntas, bienvenido a SOes, donde nos apoyamos con lo que programamos :D Si la gente de la comunidad ve un esfuerzo nulo, difícilmente tendrás respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Lo que hay que hacer es utilizar la función setInterval de javascript. Esta función lo que hace es llamar cada x milisegundos a la funcion que le pases por parámetro. Como no indicas en ningún lugar si utilizas alguna libreria para menejar el DOM. Te he escrito un ejemplo utilizando solo javascript.

```js
 /**
 * Retorna el código HTML con los tags h1 y un numero en medio.
 * @param number número a insertar
 */
function updateNumber(number) {
    return "<h1>" + number + "</h1>";
}

/**
 * Retorna el codigo HTML de un boton
 */
function createButton() {
    return "<button>Final!</button>"
}

/**
 * Contador que genera una cuenta hacia atrás.
 * @param time tiempo en ms de espera de cada intervalo.
 * @param n número de intervalos.
 */
function countdown(time,n) {
    var id = setInterval(function(){
        mainDiv = document.querySelector("#main");
        main.innerHTML = updateNumber(n);
        if(n == 0){
            mainDiv = document.querySelector("#main");
            main.innerHTML = createButton();
            clearInterval(id);
        }
        n--;
    },time);
}

countdown(1000, 5);
```

```html
  <div id="main"><h1>COUNTDOWN!</h1></div>
```

Para que el código de javascript se ejecute directamente al cargar la pagina lo he colocado al final.

Answer (score 1):

Estimado amigo, apoyo lo que dice nuestro colega fredyfx, sería bueno que vieras un tour del portal para que puedes emitir tus consultas con más detalle y así poder ayudarte mejor. Sin embargo, encontré en la web un código que hace lo que tu quieres, lo modifiqué para que quedara como la descripción que nos mencionaste de lo que deseas que haga. No es mas que un script que se ejecuta cada un segundo quitando en esta unidad a un número de segundos que tu coloques y cambia el innerHTML de un parrafo

, para que muestre cada segundo una actualización del tiempo. Cuando este llega a cero coloca otro mensaje, en esa parte puedes ejecutar la función que estimes conveniente. 
Ojalá te pueda ayudar el código que te dejo.
Saludos y que encuentres buen conocimiento.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var segundos = 10;
// Actualiza los segundos cada un segundo
var x = setInterval(function() {
 //Cambia el contenitdo del elemento con el id "demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "Quedan "+ segundos + " segundos ";
    
    //Se resta una unidad cada vez que pasa por aqui.
    segundos--;
    
    //Cuando se acabe el contador va a ejecutar la función que le coloques dentro del if.
    if (segundos < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "INICIANDO DESCARGA ...";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```